# Get dynamic data from PHP to Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, vue.js

I'm using PHP(CodeIgniter) to render a page built with vue cli.

Usually, if I want to pass a value from php to javascript I would do something like this:

```
var page = '<?php echo $page ?>';
```

But since the page is built with vue and all the js minified and all its not possible.
I need an alternative solution to get a variable in vue which is sent from php.

Comment: call API from component and fill data.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I cant. To call the API I need to know the id of the page which is rendered like `page/id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:here the js variable msg2 prints the php varible $test value= "Chris"

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
         <p>{{ msg2 }}</p>
        <?php
        $test = "Chris";
        ?>
      </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {

               message: 'My first VueJS Task',
               msg2: "<?php echo $test ?>"
            }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should renounce the idea of passing `var page = '<?php echo $page ?>';` into JS.

**1. Check your routes** - i'm assuming that you still have PHP pages with logic and that Vue is on a sepparate Controller.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home'; 

// Create a new controller with the name Vue before adding the routes.
$route['vue'] = 'Vue'; // default page
$route['vue/(:any)'] = 'Vue/$1'; // vue/with-any-passing/value/you/want
```

**2. Controller: Vue.php**

```
<?php
class Vue extends CI_Controller {

        public function index( $uri_for_vue = '' )
        {
          $vueSetup = array(
             'settings' => array(
                'vueURL'=> $uri_for_vue
             )
          );

          $this->load->view('vueView', $vueSetup);

        }
}
```

**3. View: vueView.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>vue page</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
         <p>{{ msg2 }}</p>
        <?php
        $test = "Chris";
        ?>
      </div>
      <script id='vue-elem' data-vue='<?php echo json_encode($settings)?>' type = "text/javascript"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript">

         var vueElem = document.getElementById('vue-elem');
         var vueSettings = JSON.parse(vueElem.getAttribute("data-vue"));

         // you may want to remove the element from html after it's contents is loaded in js, or reset the 
         // vueElem .setAttribute("data-vue", "{}"); 

         // you will want to add this line in the minified version so vue can self-load    
         var page = vueSettings.vueURL; 
         console.log('page url', page );

         // now you can load vue

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```